# Error on simple standalone script

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, error, ubuntu, display

I want to develop a PyQGIS standalone script only using Ubuntu terminal, so to start I use:

```
from qgis.core import *
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/path/to/qgis/installation", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()
qgs.exitQgis()
```

But it gives me the next error:

```
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Could not connect to any X display.
```

I understand that the error is due cause I'm not using a graphic device (I'm working through Ubuntu's terminal and I can't use a graphic device), but the second argument on QgsApplication() disables the GUI so I thought a graphic device wouldn't be necessary.

What does that error mean? Does it have any solution?

Comment: `QgsApplication` inherit from `QApplication`  and then you need to use `QCoreApplication` instead of `QApplication` i think, chek this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979185/qt-5-1-qapplication-without-display-qxcbconnection-could-not-connect-to-displ

Comment: Any idea on this issue? I get the same error running app = QgsApplication([], gui_flag): QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Could not connect to any X display.